# Password storing in 2017

Tags: algorithm, hash, salt, storing-information, pepper

So I'm working on my own website with my login system.
I am working on the password storing part and have been looking at a couple of youtube videos where peoples tell me not to use things like md5 because it's outdated.

I looked at the video Tom Scott made about how NOT to store passwords and he told us to look up a recent tutorial on how to do it properly.

For my project I really need to store the passwords myself and not use anything like Facebook or Google for logins.

I looked at a lot of websites and questions here on Stack Overflow but can't seem to find anything from this year where it is all explained.

So now I'm wondering what is the best way in 2017 to store passwords?
Do I need to use a Salt and a Pepper? Maybe something else? And which hashing algorithm is the best at this moment? If possible I'd like to use this within php.

Can anyone help me out with these questions?

Thank you :)

Comment: [I suggest you take a look at the answers to this question at crypto.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4781/76890)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a security question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you just want to store passwords for user authentication, and you asked for a PHP solution explicitely, so the answer must be to use the PHP function password_hash(). This function is up to date and handles all the tricky parts of password hashing.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

If you are interested in more indept information, you could have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about safely storing passwords.